# What is the best way to store cookie information?

Tags: php, cookies

I need to store information about shopping products added to buy.
I'm thinking to create a cookie with a encrypted value that will be stored in a database along with data associated with that cookie, and based on client cookie to retrieve information from database. No Login, No Session.

Comment: Do you require the user to login? Then just store the cart in the database, keyed off the username.

Comment: Ever heard of session cookies?

Comment: no login, without authentication, information will required when send the order.

Comment: Save info to session

Comment: session cookies - I know that session will create a cookie.
I don't want session is not with authentication. From what I know session will consume memory.I know that session will be destroyed after logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create cookie as

```
$name='john';
$value=1;
setcookie($name,$value,time() + (86400 * 30));
```

and then You can create a database 'cookie_db' and can insert these cookies simply as

```
$query='insert into cookie_db values($name,$_COOKIE[$name'])';
```

hope it helps!!

Comment: Like this I thought myself. But I will create a cookie that store a encrypted key as a value and values of encrypted key will be stored in a table like this:
table_cookie: value_cookie_encrypted_key,  values

The point is I don't want that client to figure out what cookie values means. I think it is a security thing. It's a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are definitely the way to go. The only way the session gets destroyed is if the user closes the browser or the expiry time exceeds. Which is configurable through php.ini.

Try this

```
// Start a session
session_start();

// Add values to the session
$_SESSION["cart_items"] = array("item 1", "item 2");
```

Now the session var should be accessible after calling session_start() from page to page.

Session will automatically add a cookie, and will retrieve the data as needed.

See this: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

And this:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("cookie_name","cookie_value", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

or you can set cookie with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays)
{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
setCookie('cookie_name','data_of_cookie');
</script>
```

i hope this will help you